# How to setup the timeout before a refresh on Twitter embedded timelines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, twitter

## How can I setup the timeout before a refresh on Twitter embedded timelines?

I need change the timeout time to update the twitter timelines on my site.
Currently each second the twitter API do a ajax request to update the timelines.
But on browser with slow engines of JS (in other words: IE), causes the browser becomes slow or sometimes causes the browser to stop working.

To fix this I want setup the timeout before a refresh on Twitter timelines

I didn't found any reference on API about how I can do this.

I'm using the follow JS code to import the timeline:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p='https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

To show the timelines I'm using a HTML like code shown below:

```
<div class="box-twitter">
<p class="title-box"><span class="icon"></span>WHAT'S HAPPENING ON TWITTER </p>
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/search?q=from:dev include:retweets"  data-widget-id="394816085830025216"><img src="preloader.gif" style="margin-left: 132px; margin-top: 20px;"/></a>
```

Someone know how can  I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `twitter api` loaded timelines refreshed every second.  This causes performance issues on `IE10` and `IE11`?

Comment: I've only found this performance issues only on IE7, IE8 and IE9. I didn't test on IE10 and IE11.

Comment: I'll remove my answer for now if it looks like its not solving your problem..  But that makes me think that its not the `updating or polling` of the twitter timelines that is causing the problem because setting a `data-tweet-limit` should stop the polling for updates `completely`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After do a reverse engineering, on widget.js file, provided by Twitter.
I've found a method called 'schedulePolling', with the code below:

```
schedulePolling: function(e) {
var t = this;
if (this.pollInterval === null) return;
e = twttr.widgets.poll || e || this.pollInterval || 1e4, e > -1 && window.setTimeout(function() {
    this.isUpdating || t.update(), t.schedulePolling()
}, e)
```

To increase the timeout I've added a fixed value on this code.

```
schedulePolling: function(e) {
var t = this;
if (this.pollInterval === null) return;
e = 60000 || e || this.pollInterval || 1e4, e > -1 && window.setTimeout(function() {
    this.isUpdating || t.update(), t.schedulePolling()
}, e)}
```

I've replaced the code `twttr.widgets.poll`
for the time that I wanted '60000';

After do this a save the widget.js with my customized code.

So, after this customization I've modify the line where the Twitter API was imported, changing the default value `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` to the path of my customized file `my-site/js/customized_widgets.js`.

This is the result.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p='https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"/my-site/js/customized_widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe setting a `Tweet limit` could be an option.

**Tweet limit:** `To fix the size of a timeline to a preset number of Tweets, use the` **data-tweet-limit="5" attribute** `with any value between 1 and 20 Tweets. The timeline will render the specified number of Tweets from the timeline, expanding the height of the widget to display all Tweets without scrolling.` **Since the widget is of a fixed size, it will not poll for updates when using this option.**

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

e.g.

`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE" data-chrome="nofooter" data-tweet-limit="3">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>`

And then if desired you could update your widgets manually, by removing them reinserting the html then calling.

`twttr.widgets.load()`

Comment: That wasn't enough. Into another page this performance issue still happens.

The problem are caused because the multiples request made by twitter API makes a overhead the JS engine of browser.

Comment: @SamuelFreitas That's odd according to twitter if you use that option the widget won't poll for updates. I'll have to test it on my end later and see what I find.

Comment: That's right. But on my page has three timelines. So when I add this attribute value order still remained high.

Comment: And i'm assuming you set the `data-tweet-limit` for all three of your timelines?  What happens if you set the limit to something ridiculously low like `1`?

Comment: To reduce the overhead, instead of update the timeline each second, I want run the update once per minute.

Comment: I've tried the function "twttr.widgets.load()" to refresh the widgets manually, but it didn't work as you said.

Comment: @SamuelFreitas It only loads the widgets from html it does not refresh them.  Like if you were to dynamically add the `twitter widget html` after the page was loaded. To get the timeline to show up you could call `twttr.widgets.load()`